# Code stops working once turned into function (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a Monte Carlo simulation in Python and I have a bit of code which should replicate certain rows in a matrix. When I initially wrote the code it looked like this:

```
newReplicas = []

for j in range( len(replicas) ):
    replica = replicas[j]
    r2 = 0
    for x in replica:
        r2 += x * x
        V = 0.5 * mass * w**2 * r2
        W = exp(-(V - ER) / rootT)
        mn = int(W + random.uniform(0,1))
        if mn >= 3:
            newReplicas.append( replica )
            newReplicas.append( replica )
            newReplicas.append( replica )
        elif mn == 2:    
            newReplicas.append( replica )
            newReplicas.append( replica )
        elif mn == 1:
            newReplicas.append( replica )
replicas = newReplicas
```

This works absolutely fine but when I make it a function, it stops working completely and no rows ever get replicated. Here is the code after I have attempted to convert it to a function:

```
def branch(replicas): 
    newReplicas = []
    for j in range( len(replicas) ):
        replica = replicas[j]
        r2 = 0
        for x in replica:
            r2 += x * x
        V = 0.5 * mass * w**2 * r2
        W = exp(-(V - ER) / rootT)
        mn = int(W + random.uniform(0,1))
        if mn >= 3:
            newReplicas.append( replica )
            newReplicas.append( replica )
            newReplicas.append( replica )
        elif mn == 2:    
            newReplicas.append( replica )
            newReplicas.append( replica )
        elif mn == 1:
            newReplicas.append( replica )
    replicas = newReplicas

branch(replicas)

print(replicas)
```

The values that I have been using are as follows:

```
mass = 1
w = 1
ER = 0.5
rootT = sqrt(0.02)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean it stops working? What do you expect it to do? What is it doing that is wrong?

Comment: 'replicas = newReplicas' this line gets rid of the reference to the original list and sets `replicas` to point to your `newReplicas` variable. instead, have a `return newReplicas` in the end of the function and have a line in your code like `replicas = branc(replicas)` to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return your replicas inside the function and call the function

```
def branch(replicas):
    # code here
    return new_replicas
```

then somewhere else call it

```
print branch(replicas)
```

a function can do anything you want it to, but to actually execute the code you have to call that function by typing the name of it (in your case `branch` and add parenthesis afterwards to call the function. since your function takes an argument you have to pass through whatever they are in your function call aka `branch(replicas)`

if you want to use those replicas after executing the function then assign a variable to them

```
new_replicas = branch(replicas)
```

Comment: You'd also need to assign a variable to the result, i.e. `x = branch(replicas)`

Comment: @JohnGordon yes if the OP wants to use those new replicas for something after transforming them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the function in order for it to run:

```
branch(something)
```

Comment: What I'm saying is that when I call the function on my matrix it doesn't do anything to the matrix. However the first block of code replicates random rows of he matrix. The only thing that I've changed between the two is defining the code as a function and then calling it on my matrix (although I didn't show the calling of the function in my post).

Answer (score 0):

The function has to return or print something or assign some value to a global variable. Otherwise, there is no point to use it. Secondly, you have to call it somewhere out of the function itself.

```
def fucn1():
    ..
   return variable

def fucn2():
    ..
   print variable

def fucn3(v):
    global value
    ..
    value = variable

print func1()
func2()
func3(v1)
```